# AJAX call to delete DB record

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have a page that displays a list of courses for an individual.  The page allows a user to delete a course from the selected users course list.  When the delete button is clicked, that course should be deleted from the course list and the list of courses should be re-displayed.  In my controller I was trying to delete the record, then call the listCourses view (view that initially lists the courses for a user) but when I click the delete button, nothing happens.  Below is my code:

View to select a student:

```
@foreach (var stu in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="stulisttd">
                    @stu.Id
                </td>
                <td class="stulisttd">
                    @stu.fname
                </td>
                <td class="stulisttd">
                    @stu.lname
                </td>
                <td class="thEditButton">
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("addCourses", "ManageStudentCourses", stuEditCourses))
                    {
                        @Html.TextBox("stuId", (string)stu.Id, new { @class = "listCourseText" })
                        <input type="submit" id="addCourses" name="addCourses" value='Add Courses' class="AllTracksButtons" />
                    }
                </td>
                <td class="thEditButton">
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("listCourses", "ManageStudentCourses", stuEditCourses))
                    {
                        @Html.TextBox("stuId", (string)stu.Id, new { @class = "listCourseText" })
                        <input type="submit" value="List Courses" class="AllTracksButtons" id=@stu.Id />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

View that lists the courses for user selected:

```
@foreach (var course in Model)
    {
        using (Ajax.BeginForm("deleteCourses", "ManageStudentCourses", stuListEditCourses))
        {
            <tr class="trCourseList">

                <td>
                    @course.courseAbNum
                    @Html.TextBox("courseAbNum", (string)course.courseAbNum, new { @class = "editCourseText" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @course.courseDesc
                </td>
                <td>
                    @course.status
                </td>
                <td>
                    @course.grade
                </td>
                <td>
                    @course.credits
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="courseListButtons" id="displayEdit" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

deleteCourses controller:

```
public PartialViewResult deleteCourses(string courseAbNum)
    {
        KuPlanEntities db = new KuPlanEntities();

        var deleteCourse = (from course in db.COURSE_TAKEN
                            where course.courseAbNum == courseAbNum && course.Id == "000160228"
                            select course);
        foreach (var course in deleteCourse)
        {
            db.COURSE_TAKEN.Remove(course);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        var stuCourses = (from studCourse in db.COURSE_TAKEN
                          join course in db.COURSEs on studCourse.courseAbNum equals course.courseAbNum
                          where studCourse.Id == "000160228"
                          select new courseListViewModel { id = studCourse.Id, courseAbNum = studCourse.courseAbNum, status = studCourse.status, grade = studCourse.grade, courseDesc = course.courseDesc, credits = course.credits });

        return PartialView("~/Views/ManageStudentCourses/listCourses.cshtml", stuCourses);
    }
```

Comment: What is `stuListEditCourses` in `Ajax.BeginForm()`? Is you controller being hit?

Comment: it tells ajax what to replace on the page

Comment: So its the the `AjaxOptions`? as in somthing like `new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="someElement"}`? Is your controller being hit?

Comment: yea thats what it is.  I am using the same code outline that I use to call for the list of courses which works.  Im not sure if it is even being hit to be honest.  How can I check?  still new to mvc method

Comment: Try to put a break point inside your controller method and see if it's hit when you click the delete button

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have an issue with this code

```
foreach (var course in deleteCourse)
    {
        db.COURSE_TAKEN.Remove(course);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

You'll likely get the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

To get around this you can use this hack

```
 while (db.COURSE_TAKEN.Where(x => x.ID == ID).Count() != 0)
        {
            COURSE_TAKEN course = db.COURSE_TAKEN.Where(x => x.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
            db.COURSE_TAKEN.Remove(course);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Hope this helps.